# Install Zabbix agent on CentOS

Tags: installation, centos7, zabbix

I'm trying to install Zabbix 3.4 on CentOS 7 but I have problems with the first step : Adding the Zabbix repository to the CentOS 7 system.
[URL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0c5Y.png)

I don't know what's wrong. Any suggestion? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you type this URL manually? Seems there is a typo in the `el17` part which should be `el7`. As much as it is possible, try to always copy-paste URLs to avoid this problem in the future:

```
rpm -ivh https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.4-2.el7.noarch.rpm
```